# How Do I Find Which Session Variables are Storing Data in Rails2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am working with some session data in a Rails site that was created before my time. One of the session variables is not working and I'd like to see what variables exist in my session. Is there a way to get key/value pairs for my session variables and then print them out in the log?

Comment: in a view, you can add (if you use .erb) `<%= session.inspect %>` and you will see the content of the session Hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the default log level of info:

```
Rails.logger.info(session.inspect)
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
Rails.logger.error(session.inspect)
```